# Trying to use "if" with a user inputted string

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program where I enter the name of a shape and it tells me how many sides it has. I cannot seem to get it to work. Can anyone explain how to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shapes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String shape;

    System.out.print("Enter shape: ");
    shape = reader.next();

    if (shape == "hexagon") {
        System.out.println("A hexagon has 6 sides.");
    }

    if (shape == "decagon"); {
        System.out.println("A decagon has 10 sides.");
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `String` values, use `String`'s `equals` method instead.

Comment: Strings should be always compared using `equals()` method not using `==`

Comment: If you are using Java 7, you can use a switch statement on the `switch` object.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you want to use .equals() with a string.

For example:

```
if(shape.equals("hexagon"))
```

Since the == operator is asking whether or not the String object `shape` is exactly the same thing as "hexagon" (which it isn't - hexagon is a constant and `shape` is an object).

Answer (score 0):

Objects are compared with `equals` in Java:

```
if (shape.equals("hexagon")) {
    System.out.println("A hexagon has 6 sides.");
}
```

Only the value of primitive types (int, long, double, etc.) can be compared with `==`. If you compare objects with `==` you compare the [object identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28object-oriented_programming%29), not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shape.equals("triangle")` in if

The operator, ==, tests to see if two object reference variables refer to the exact same instance of an object.

The method, .equals(), tests to see if the two objects being compared to each other are equivalent -- but they need not be the exact same instance of the same object.

You can use == with primitive types. For String use equals()

Comment: I used the shape.equals("hexagon"). but now when I type in hexagon it gives me both "A hexagon has 6 sides" and "A decagon has 10 sides"

Comment: use if and else if and use .equals() method in both conditions

Comment: This is what I have and it is still doing the same thing.      System.out.print("Enter shape: ");
  shape = reader.next();
  
  if(shape.equals("hexagon")) {
   System.out.println("A hexagon has 6 sides.");
  }
  
  else if(shape.equals("decagon")); {
   System.out.println("A decagon has 10 sides.");
  }